# Visual Studio modify default install path

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2013, disk

I renamed my SSD 'E' letter to D and My visual studio now not working. I already removed files. I would like install again to the 'D' drive but i got this message and i can't select directory.. How can i change the default directory? Now the E is reserved for system..
Visual studio problem:
https://prnt.sc/YoYjpEcENvNz
Partitions:
https://prnt.sc/MpV4Jh-jg18c
I need my visual studio for work so i very happy if someone can help me for solve my problem.
Thank you before!

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve my problem than i reinstalled my PC..